# Null reference exception on boolean, inside custom nested arrays of classes

Tags: c#

I've created a set of custom classes to contain some information I need, in specific order. Each class, besides the last class, contains an array of the class underneath it.

The custom classes are as follows.

```
public class Quote
{
    public int ServiceQuoteId;

    public bool Begin = new bool();

    public PricingGroup[] PricingOptionGroup = new PricingGroup[10];
}
public class PricingGroup
{
    public int ItemId;

    public string ALocation;

    public bool LocSet = new bool();

    public Product[] Group = new Product[10];
}
public class Product
{
    public int Total1;

    public ProductGroup[] Set = new ProductGroup[10];

    public string Term;
}
public class ProductGroup
{
    public string Product;

    public int Charge;

    public bool Option = new bool();
}
```

After creating an instance of the object, like this (below)

```
Quote testQuote = new Quote();
```

I try to test one of the boolean values like this (below.

```
if (!testQuote.PricingOptionGroup[0].LocSet)
```

But this gives me this error.

```
"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebApplication3.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

What I'm trying to do might not be possible; but logically I believe it makes sense. To my understanding, new bool() initializes to false.

Comment: I agree with the closing.  OP - you've allocated *storage* for your array, but not actually allocated any instances of it.  `PricingOptionGroup[0]` is null.

Comment: Does this not initialize it?

Quote testQuote = new Quote();

Comment: Yes, but not a `PricingGroup`.

Comment: Inside the quote object I do this

public PricingGroup[] PricingOptionGroup = new PricingGroup[10];

Does that not initialize my array?

Comment: No, it does not.  It allocates storage for 10.  You'd still need to go, something like:  `PricingOptionGroups[0] = new PricingGroup()`.  Without wanting to sound dismissive, I think you need to read up on how C# works - specifically arrays and collections - and then revisit what you're trying to do.  Also research properties (get/set methods), and the differences between value types and reference types.

Comment: I don't think I need to relearn C# because of one simple error. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've allocated space for 10 ProductOptionGroups, but you didn't actually put any in there.

Here's one way to initialize the ProductOptionGroups:

```
public class Quote
{
    public int ServiceQuoteId;

    public bool Begin = new bool();

    public PricingGroup[] PricingOptionGroup = new PricingGroup[10];
    public Quote(){

        PricingOptionGroup=Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i=>new PricingGroup()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Here's another:

```
public class Quote
{
    public int ServiceQuoteId;

    public bool Begin = new bool();

    public PricingGroup[] PricingOptionGroup = { 
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup(),
        new PricingGroup()
    };
}
```

Comment: Would I have to do this then? 

            Quote testQuote = new Quote();
            testQuote.PricingOptionGroup = new PricingGroup[10];

Comment: Updated with one way of initializing the array.

Comment: I like it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It worked great by the way. Thanks for answering my question. They marked it as a duplicate question but the answer they linked it to didn't explain the array allocation clearly like this. Thanks a ton Robert.